# Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string - PHP error

Tags: php

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /home/tvstartstbiz/public_html/mng-channel/vpanel/inc/timefunc.php on line 49

This is the error I am receiving. I am not sure why I'm getting it and I can't seem to figure out why. I've googled it, but none of the solutions worked out for me. I don't think its a version problem because I tried this code on version 7 and version 5 and I got the error on both versions so I am stunned at this error.

```
function isdatedst($date)
{
    $date = new DateTime($date);

    // $date get date

    return $date->format('I');

    // date("I", $date);

}

function istzdst($floffset, $date)
{
    $wtz = floatval($floffset);
    $tzflag = 1.0;
    if ($wtz < 0)
    {
        $tzflag = - 1.0;
        $atz = $wtz * $tzflag;
    }

    $itz = intval($wtz);
    $dtz = doubleval($itz);
    $ftz = $wtz - $dtz;
    $minutestz = 60.0 * $ftz;
    $offset = $dtz . ":" . $minutestz;
    $currenttimezone = date_default_timezone_get();

    // Calculate seconds from offset

    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $offset);
    $seconds = $hours * 60 * 60 + $minutes * 60;

    // Get timezone name from seconds

    $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $seconds, 1);

    // Workaround for bug #44780

    if ($tz === false) $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $seconds, 0);

    // Set timezone

    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
```

**line 49** below

```
    $isdstdate = isdatedst($date . " " . $tz);
    date_default_timezone_set($currenttimezone);
    return $isdstdate;
}
```

Comment: what value you pass in this function `istzdst`? can you vardump it?

Comment: yes i did i was passing in wrong date format @Ben

Comment: that fixed my error @Ben